# How to Ignores the second value, and puts the first value in a context in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell and just learned Functors.Im having trouble coding an expression such that  it ignores the second value of any type and puts the first value in context . e.g

```
 1 <$ Just 6 --> Just 1
 3 <$ [1,2,3] --> [3,3,3]
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried?

Comment: `x <$ y = pure x` with right type signature. This won't give you `[3,3,3]`, though, but `[3]`.

Comment: Why does the code you provided not work for you. To me it looks like it puts the "first value in a context".

Comment: @arrowd: `3 <$ [1,2,3]` is `[3,3,3]` since `x <$ y` is equivalent to `const x <$> y`.

Comment: @arrowd: `const . pure :: Applicative f => b -> f b`, whereas @Sandy is trying to write `(<$) :: Functor f => b -> f a -> f b`. Not every functor is an applicative.

Comment: @Micha Weidenmann: Those are examples of usage, not definitions of `(<$)`.

Answer (score 1):

Every `Functor` `f` is equipped with `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)`. You want to write `(<$) :: Functor f => b -> (f a -> f b)`. How might you go about doing this? Notice that the right-hand sides (i.e., return types) of each function type are identical. If you can turn a value of type `b` into a function of type `a -> b`, then you can call `fmap` on that function.